# How to use ng-class to combine classes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to combine classes using ng-class. I want to use `save` class plus `firstClass` if `something = First`.
I am pretty new to angular and have been doing some reading on how to use ng-class but have not been able to find a solution. 
Is there a better way to approach this?

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="modal-title-box">
    <div id="holdtitle" class="modal-title">Do {{something}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="some-text">Are you sure you want to delete {{something | lowercase}}?</div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button id="cancelBtn" class="cancel" (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button id="holdBtn" class="save ng-class= something ='First': 'firstClass' ? 'secondClass'" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Hold</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do that.

```html
<button mat-button class="save" [ngClass]="something === 'First' ? 'firstClass' : 'secondClass'"></button>
<button mat-button class="save" [class.firstClass]="something === 'First'"
    [class.secondClass]="something !== 'First'"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always find the `ng-class` syntax hard to use.

```
<button mat-button id="holdBtn" class="save"
    ng-class="{'firstClass': something == 'First', 'secondClass': something != 'First'}" 
    [mat-dialog-close]="true">Hold</button>
```

This will always apply the `save` class, and then if `something == 'First'` will apply `firstClass`, otherwise apply `secondClass`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Angular (v2+), based on the `(click)` syntax in your markup.

You have a couple of options for achieving the functionality of dynamically adding / removes classes on an element with Angular.

The important thing to know here is that the `ngClass` directive sets the entire class list for the element. So you can include multiple classes in the same string, as long as they are separated by spaces (just like you would with normal `class="..."`). (Example: `[ngClass]="'save firstClass'"` will apply both the `save` class and the `firstClass` class to the element.

Now, to set the class list based on a condition (such as `something === First`)...

**Using the [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive:**

```
<button [ngClass]="something === First ? 'save firstClass' : 'secondClass'" >
</button>
```

**Using the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) attribute:**

```
<button [classList]="something === First ? 'save firstClass' : 'secondClass'" >
</button>
```

**Note:** with the above two approaches, you run the risk of affecting existing classes on the element. For example, if you want `save` to *always* be included in the class list for that element, you'll need to list it in both branches of your ternary expression (before the `:` and after the `:`).

---

Another way, which I consider the best since you do not run the risk of overwriting existing classes on the element, is to do the work in your component, using the [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to dynamically `addClass` or `removeClass` from your DOM node's class list, accessing the element with [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

**Using `Renderer2`:**

```
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  something = 'first';
  @ViewChild('span') span: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.something === 'first') {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.span.nativeElement, 'red-border');
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.span.nativeElement, 'red-border');
    }
  }
}
```

This final approach is superior because it guarentees the other classes are preserved, but it adds a bit of boilerplate adding template `#ref`s and using `@ViewChild`. I used the `DoCheck` lifecycle hook assuming the value of `something` can change, but you could use a different lifecycle hook, like `OnInit`, if that value is static.

Here is a link to a working app with all three approaches demonstrated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-change-classes.